# Showing warning on the result - loop for

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, warnings

I have this script to alter my offset in a request to api.
When i send, i have success in result, because it bring me what i want.
But, in top of the page, saw  this error: **Warning: Undefined variable $offset in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_lp\Complementares\testeforeach.php on line 16**

I know thats appear because my variable was declare inside de for loop, but what i need do to fix this warning given that my code is ok?

There is my code:

```
$request = 3000;

For($i=0 ;  $offset < $request ; $i++){
$limit = 100;
$offset = $limit*$i;
echo "<pre>";
echo $offset . " " .  $limit;
echo "</pre>";
}
```

Thx for helping.

Comment: Declare `$offset` above for loop

Comment: Tks guy, i forgot this possibilitie, tks so much

Answer (score 0):

How i solve, with the help of @nice_dev:

```
$request = 3000;
$limit = 100;
$offset = 0;

For($i=0 ;  $offset < $request ; $i++){
$limit = 100;
$offset = $limit*$i;
echo "<pre>";
echo $offset . " " .  $limit;
echo "</pre>";
}
```